# Reconnecting to long running query on SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Been running a query which has run for 7 days and was near its end, when I got a network error:

> Msg 121, Level 20, State 0, Line 0
> A transport-level error has occurred when receiving results from the server. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - The semaphore timeout period has expired.)

The query is still running in its process on SQL Server and is not yet rolling back.

It was looping through 10 parameters and then for each parameter carrying out however many updates were required to match up all the records somewhere between 10 and 50 updates per parameter until no rows were effected and them moving onto the next parameter.

It had reached the point were only 1 row was being updated at a time on the last parameter after 7 days when I had a short network drop.

I have used dirty read to copy the results out to a different table.

It still shows up in ActivityManager (active expensive queries), and `sp_who`/`sp_who2` and using `sys.sysprocesses`.

After the update statement it should go on to print out the number of iterations and then de-allocate the parameters that were passed in through a cursor.

It is a `while rowcount > 0` inside a `while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0` where the cursor is going through a comma separated list of parameters.

Looking at `sys.sysprocesses`, the CPU count continues to increase and it shows 2 open_tran

Is it possible to connect to a specific process in SQL Server?

If so what client can I use (SQL Server Management Studio, code, or OS mssql on linux)?

If not possible to connect, can I monitor to see if it completes?

Any other suggestions?

Comment: You don't. If the connection died then the transaction is likely now being rolled back. If you have a query that needs 7 days to run, I would suggest that there are multiple performance issues you need to address and also you should be batching, so that in the event of a failure you don't have to start over, and you should be running it on the host so that you can't lose connection.

Comment: *Any other suggestions?* Consider asking a question about the actual query design and performance, not always but very often a cursor or loop is simply not required and costs an exponentional amount of overhead.

Comment: @lamu, If running a single batch and that I know will take days, I would run it serverside. Thanks

Comment: @Stu The cursor was looping through a comma delimited parameter list turned into a table with  from string_Split(@comma_delimited_list,',') so minimal overhead,  
The core had multiple joins on 3 tables and 2 not exists in the inner most aggregate sub query and the optimizer was doing strange things.

It was not so bad on the previous set of updates, which took about 4 min per loop.

It is all throw away code since this was a unique mess I was tiding up, to import data.

Comment: To ping someone, @RonaldDuncan , you need to spell their name correctly.

Comment: @Larnu The client could lose the connection and the server might not realize until a few minutes have passed. In that case `KILL` is useful. Obviously you need to wait for the rollback also.

Comment: This is why I said it is *likely* rolling back, @Charlieface ; there could be scenarios where the server isn't aware, but it *normally* is (or should be at least shortly afterwards).

Answer (score 0):

I used a dirty read to copy all the data out of the table being updated.

The query did complete, it continued running for about an hour and then committed everything prior to the process ending.

I was then able to compare the dirty read copy against the final results.

Next time I go for updating with a loop until no more updates, I will put in a go to commit as it goes along.

It was roughly 1,000 ten minute update queries that were run.  The previous set up update queries were about 4 min each, so I looped them up with parameters, one mistake since it was easy to was to add in 10 parameters rather than 5 so 7 days vs 3.5 days, and an initial estimate of 1.5 days.

Comment: Is this an answer? It doesn't read like one.

Comment: Sorry, @Larnu It is more of a comment, but the query is now complete, so I can not test out any brilliant ways of reconnecting to it.

Clearly if someone knows how to connect to a running SQL Server process, that would be the answer.

A bit like the linux screen command to allow you to keep a terminal session and pass it around.

However, dirty read does give you a picture of what has been updated so far.

Comment: As I've stated you can't restore a connection once it's been lost.